# Error trying to "print" list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have the following problem: given a max(max) apacity, and given a list of values(listOfValues) i need to return a list with values from the listOfValues. The sum of the elements must be <= max and i need to prioritize the higher values.

Example: typing solvingProblem 103 [15, 20, 5, 45, 34] i must get: [45, 45, 5, 5]

To solve the problem i create the following code:

```
solvingProblem max [] = 0
solvingProblem max listOfValues | max == 0 = 0
                                | otherwise = createList max listOfValues []


createList max [] result = -1
createList max listOfValues result | smaller listOfValues > max = -1
                               | higher listOfValues > max = createList max (remove (higher listOfValues) listOfValues) result
                               | otherwise = createList (max - higher listOfValues) listOfValues (insert (higher listOfValues) result)

higher [a] = a
higher (a:b:x) | a > b = higher (a:x)
              | otherwise = higher (b:x)

smaller [a] = a
smaller (a:b:x) | a < b = smaller (a:x)
              | otherwise = smaller (b:x)

remove x [] = []
remove x (h:t) | x == h = remove x t
                | otherwise = h : remove x t

insert x (h:t) = x : h : t
```

In the two lines where i'll returning "-1" should be the parameter "result", but if i change "-1" to "result" the code don't load on ghci.

Can someone help me?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Always add type signatures for your functions. They make the code more readable and idiomatic, and most importantly allow GHC to check your functions indeed return what you intended to, often greatly improving the type error messages. Further, in the future, when asking on SO, if you receive an error from the compiler, post it! It contains valuable information for us, even if it might tell little to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I may begin with a bit of a side note, some of your functions already exist in Haskell (now that I come to think of it you might have written them for an exercise, but just in case it wouldn't be the case, let's discuss that): your `higher` is `maximum`, your `smaller` is `minimum` and your insert is just `(:)`, beacause like you write it yourself `insert x list = x:list`. Note that your version will fail if you give it the empty list because the pattern matching is non-exhaustive. Also you could write `remove` in terms of filter: `remove x list = filter (== x) list`.

Now why doesn't your code load properly? `ghci` tells you:

```
• Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
• When checking the inferred type
    solvingProblem :: forall a.
                      (Ord a, Num [a], Num a) =>
                      a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Which I agree is pretty cryptic, but what it's saying is that the return type of `solvingProblem` is a list of `a` and for some reason it is also an instance of the `Num` type class. The reason why it says it's an instance of `Num` is because one of the return value of `solvingProblem` is `0` which is a number, which is a bit odd because it is also a list. Changing the 0 with `[]` makes the code compile and work (if you change `insert` with `(:)` otherwise you get the non-exhaustive pattern matching I was talking about earlier).

```
λ> solvingProblem 103 [15,20, 5, 45, 34]
[5,5,45,45]
it :: (Ord t, Num t) => [t]
```

Comment: Hi villou24. Thank you for the reply. I think I understand what you said, but i changed
solvingProblem max [] = 0
solvingProblem max listOfValues | max == 0 = 0

to
solvingProblem max [] = []
solvingProblem max listOfValues | max == 0 = []

and it don't compile

Comment: Have you changed the `-1` with `result`? What is the error saying?

Comment: now i did (: . sorry for that. it compile now. the error now is  Non-exhaustive patterns in function insert, probably semantics problem. I'll try to solve this now. Thank you very very much

Comment: and about the functions that already exists, some of the ones you quote i already knew and some not, but i can't use any of them in this project. but thank you anyway for that tip

Comment: No problem ;) Your non-exhaustive pattern matching is due to the fact that insert is not defined for empty lists, you can either add a case `insert x [] = [x]` or straight-away say `insert = (:)`

Comment: i was getting an error by using : but i think it was because of the problem you just solved. now it works and i don't need the insert funcion (: . once again, thank you very much and sorry for my english

Comment: if you don't bother i wanted to ask one more thing

Comment: Sure, what is it ?

Comment: i'm using ((higher listOfValues):result), so i'm getting [5,5,45,45]. so, to get [45,45,5,5] i tried to use (result:(higher listOfValues)), but it won't compile

Comment: That's normal, `(:)` appends an element at the beginning of a list, it takes an `a` on the left and `[a`] as the second argument, so flipping the arguments is a type error. If you want to have the list in the right order, you can either apply `reverse`  to `createList` in `solvingProblem` of use `(++)` which takes two list and concatenate them. Then you can call `result ++ [higher listOfValues]`, notice that I need to create a list with a single element `higher listOfValues` in order to be able to use `(++)`

Comment: Thank you very much villou24. You saved me (: Have a good night

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the last guard clause in `createList`.

The type you intended for `createList` seems to be:

```
createList :: Int -> [Int] -> Int -> Int
```

but if you look at the last guard clause you have:

```
| otherwise = createList (max - ...) listOfValues (insert ...)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                          Int        [Int]        [Int]
```

Even though GHC is very good at inferring types, always adding
type signatures to your code is a good way of catching these kinds
of errors early.

Comment: Hi ErikR. Thank you for the reply. What i need to return in the end of all is a list of integers.

 typing solvingProblem 103 [15, 20, 5, 45, 34] for example i must get: [45, 45, 5, 5]

Comment: Add type signatures to all of your functions and I'll take another look at it.

Comment: In fact, after you add type signatures it might make the problem a lot more obvious.